# Sum of digits of iterated powers of three

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $s(n)$ denote the sum of the (base $10$) digits of a number $n$. My son noticed the following curious coincidences: $s(3^{3^i})=3^{i+1}$ for $i=0,1,2,3$. Explicitly:
\begin{align*}
s(3)&=3\\
s(3^3)&=s(27)=9=3^2\\
s(3^9)&=s(19683)=27=3^3\\
s(3^{27})&=s(7625597484987)=81=3^4.
\end{align*}

The pattern fails after this point and, for example, $s(3^{81})=189\neq 243$.

Is there any "explanation" for these first four coincidences? For instance, one might argue as follows: As is well-known, the sum $s(3^{3^i})$ must be divisible by $9$ for $i>0$, and if we assume that the digits behave randomly then one might expect $s(3^{3^i})$ to be roughly $\frac{9}{2}\log_{10}3^{3^i}$ (in practice, this seems to be pretty good; for instance, $s(3^{3^6})=1557$, while the formula predicts roughly $1565$). Then we could expect $s(3^{3^i})$ to be a multiple of $9$ near to $\frac{9}{2}\log_{10}3^{3^i}$. However, this kind of argument still doesn't seem to get close to explaining the remarkable coincidence $s(3^{27})=81=3^4$ as $\frac{9}{2}\log_{10}3^{27}\approx 58$.

Is there any better explanation for this pattern?

Comment: I tried checking with Mathematica, but it takes longer than I have patience to check $i = 20$.  Is anyone out there with more number-crunching savvy in a position to check if there are any other positive integers $i$ for which $s(3^{3^i})$ equals $3^{i + 1}$?  (Incidentally, I like the visual appeal of writing it as $s(3^{3^i}) = 3\cdot3^i$ … or even $s(3^{3^i}) = 3^i s(3)$, by some sort of obtuse analogy with a logarithm.)

Comment: The Strong Law of Small Numbers.

Comment: $3,9,27,81,189$ links to https://oeis.org/A274627

Comment: Here are powers of $3$ with digit sum also a power of $3$: https://oeis.org/A067500

Comment: Under a not-unreasonable normality assumption, the implied probability that the sum-of-digits of interest is 81 or greater (rather than the 59.5 or so expected once you take into account that powers of 3 can't have zero as their first or last digit) is roughly 1.6%.  So this is a coincidence, but not a terribly rare one (as @GerryMyerson's comment says more pithily).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Unless something else comes along, it looks like I'll have to chalk this one up to the "Strong Law of Small Numbers" as suggested by @gerry.